# How to animate dynamic height change with 'height: fit-content'

Tags: css, animation, dynamic, height, css-transitions

I have a div with `height: fit-content`. While I add new *floating* text nodes to that div the div's height increases in steps to fit its new contents height.

**How can I animate this change in height similar to a hardcoded height change with** `transition: height 1s;`**?**

---

If I would know the height of the div **before** and **after** the new *floating* text nodes were attached to the div I could just use `transition: height 1s;` and set the `height` of the div to the new height after attaching child nodes. => Smoothly transitioned.

Sadly I don't know the target height (while I'd also prefer a CSS only solution) since the text is not rendered yet. Also only vanilla JS and CSS is available on my document.

See following snippet as an example which adds floating text nodes to a div. There you can see that the div's height increases in one big jump per added text node. I want it to transition smoothly instead:

```js
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => document.querySelector('div')
      .appendChild(document.createTextNode(' How to animate this change in height?')));
```

```css
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">toggle</button>

<div>
some text<br />
even more text<br />
so much text
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what do you want please explain more?

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/), which illustrates a few different ways to do what I think you want.

Comment: @BobRodes That is a nice article. Sadly it describes solutions to the *"hardcoded height => dynamic height"* transition problem. What I want to achieve is a transition for *"dynamic height => dynamic height"*.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a heavy JS way the following is a solution to the problem:

It uses two divs, one outer and one inner. The outer div is used as the transitioning, view limiting container for the inner div while the inner div contains the actual text nodes.

The inner div's height jumps like in the code of the question since its height fits its content. This jump is hidden by the outer div which has a static hardcoded height. After adding text nodes the outer div's height is updated to match the inner one (border size currently not included in calculation). Since it has a CSS `transition` for the `height` property it smoothly increases to the target size.

```js
function updateDiv() {
  outer.style.height = inner.clientHeight + 'px';
}

const inner = document.querySelector('div.inner');
const outer = document.querySelector('div.outer');

document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => {
      inner.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' How to animate this change in height?'));
      updateDiv();
    });

updateDiv();
```

```css
div.outer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s;
}

div.inner {
  background-color: purple;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">toggle</button>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    some text<br /> even more text<br /> so much text
  </div>
</div>
```